# Bundle.classNamed(_ className: String) fails but NSClassFromString() work

Tags: swift, plugins, reflection, frameworks, bundle

I'm working on a proof of concept of loading plugin from a host application in Swift. I'm able to load a framework or a bundle on a Bundle class, `NSClassFromString` and `Bundle.principalClass` seems to work fine, but I'm not able to get any result from `Bundle.classNamed` function.

This is the piece of code I'm using:

```swift
for fullName in bundles {
    print("Loading framework: \(fullName)")

    if let bundle = Bundle(path: fullName), bundle.load(),
        let name = fullName.split(separator: ".").first {

        let typeNamed = bundle.classNamed(name + ".Plugin") as? NSObject.Type
        let typeNS = NSClassFromString(name + ".Plugin") as? NSObject.Type
        let typeNamedV2 = bundle.classNamed(name + ".PluginV2") as? NSObject.Type
        let typeNSV2 = NSClassFromString(name + ".PluginV2") as? NSObject.Type
        let typePrincipal = bundle.principalClass as? NSObject.Type

        print("From bundle.classNamed: \(initPlugin(from: typeNamed)?.description ?? "")" )
        print("From NSClassFromString: \(initPlugin(from: typeNS)?.description ?? "")" )

        print("From bundle.classNamed: \(initPlugin(from: typeNamedV2)?.description ?? "")" )
        print("From NSClassFromString: \(initPlugin(from: typeNSV2)?.description ?? "")" )

        print("From bundle.principalClass: \(initPlugin(from: typePrincipal)?.description ?? "")" )

        bundle.unload()
    }
}
```

The following is the output:

```
Loading framework: One.framework
From bundle.classNamed: 
From NSClassFromString: <One.Plugin: 0x102802060>
From bundle.classNamed: 
From NSClassFromString: <One.PluginV2: 0x102802060>
From bundle.principalClass: <One.Plugin: 0x102801650>
Loading framework: CommonInterface.framework
From bundle.classNamed: 
From NSClassFromString: 
From bundle.classNamed: 
From NSClassFromString: 
From bundle.principalClass: 
Loading framework: Bundle.bundle
From bundle.classNamed: 
From NSClassFromString: <Bundle.Plugin: 0x102b08040>
From bundle.classNamed: 
From NSClassFromString: <Bundle.PluginV2: 0x102b08f80>
From bundle.principalClass: <Bundle.Plugin: 0x102801ea0>
```

Project is configured for Swift 5 and Xcode 11 building.

Here you can find the complete source code of the POC:

https://github.com/lechuckcaptain/SwiftPluginArchitectureExample

Any hint/feedback are welcome!

Comment: Note that you must not unload a bundle if any of its loaded classes are still in  use, that will make the program crash.

Comment: Noted, thanks! It was just a try to get bundle.classNamed working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `bundle.classNamed()`  does not work if the bundle has been loaded via `Bundle(path:)` and a *relative* path. Here is a minimal self-contained example demonstrating the problem:

```
// This works:

let b1 = Bundle(path: "/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework")!
print(b1.load()) // true
let c1: AnyClass? = b1.classNamed("NSString")
print(c1 as Any) // Optional(NSString)

// This does not work

FileManager.default.changeCurrentDirectoryPath("/System/Library/Frameworks")
let b2 = Bundle(path: "Foundation.framework")!
print(b2.load()) // true
let c2: AnyClass? = b2.classNamed("NSString")
print(c2 as Any) // nil
```

That looks like a bug to me. In your case a quick fix would be to load the bundle via an absolute path:

```
if let bundle = Bundle(path: "\(path)/\(fullName)")
```

Alternatively work with *URLs*, here are the necessary modifications:

```
// main.swift:

let pluginHost = PluginHost()
pluginHost.loadPlugins(at: Bundle.main.bundleURL)

// PluginHost.swift:

func loadPlugins(at url: URL) {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let bundles = (try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        .filter { $0.pathExtension == "bundle"
            || $0.pathExtension == "framework"
        }) ?? []

    for bundleURL in bundles {
        print("Loading framework: \(bundleURL)")
        if let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL) {
            let bundleName = bundleURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
            print("Name:", bundleName)

            let typeNamed = bundle.classNamed(bundleName + ".Plugin") as? NSObject.Type
            let typeNamedV2 = bundle.classNamed(bundleName + ".PluginV2") as? NSObject.Type

            print("From bundle.classNamed: \(initPlugin(from: typeNamed)?.description ?? "")" )
            print("From bundle.classNamed V2: \(initPlugin(from: typeNamedV2)?.description ?? "")" )

        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Start plugin loading
Loading framework: file:///.../One.framework/
Name: One
From bundle.classNamed: <One.Plugin: 0x100537f90>
From bundle.classNamed V2: <One.PluginV2: 0x1005388a0>
Loading framework: file:///.../CommonInterface.framework/
Name: CommonInterface
From bundle.classNamed: 
From bundle.classNamed V2: 
Loading framework: file:///.../Bundle.bundle/
Name: Bundle
From bundle.classNamed: <Bundle.Plugin: 0x10053a1d0>
From bundle.classNamed V2: <Bundle.PluginV2: 0x10053a1d0>
End plugin loading
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

*Remark:*

The plugin classes don't have to inherit from `NSObject` if you require an `init()` method in the `protocol PluginInterface` (and implement a `required init()` in all plug-ins) and load the plug-ins like this

```
if let cls = bundle.classNamed(bundleName + ".Plugin") as? PluginInterface.Type {
    let plugin = cls.init()
    plugin.doSomething()
}
if let cls = bundle.classNamed(bundleName + ".PluginV2") as? PluginInterface.Type {
    let plugin = cls.init()
    plugin.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Really appreciated, I'll update the example repository accordingly.

Comment: @lechuckcaptain: It was fun to figure this out – although it took me quite a while to isolate the actual problem!